Optional providers in terraform
I have azurerm and azureapi providers that are subscription specific.  E.g.,
provider "azurerm" {
  alias                      = "first"
  tenant_id                  = "<>"
  subscription_id            = var.subscription_id
  skip_provider_registration = true
  use_oidc                   = true
  features {}
}


provider "azapi" {
  alias           = "first-api"
  tenant_id       = "<>"
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  use_oidc        = true
}


I then also use terraform config files to change out the subscription_id.
I would like to deploy the same set of resources across multiple subscriptions in one config file but not others.  That is, for dev.tfvars subscription_id is "" but in prod.tfvars it would have a value.
I'm not sure the best way to do this because if I try to use "" for the subscription id I am getting failures.
provider "azurerm" {
  alias                      = "second"
  tenant_id                  = "<>"
  subscription_id            = var.other_subscription_id <-- defaulted to "" in the variables
  skip_provider_registration = true
  use_oidc                   = true
  features {}
}


provider "azapi" {
  alias           = "second-api"
  tenant_id       = "<>"
  subscription_id = var.other_subscription_id
  use_oidc        = true
}


yields:
Error: building account: unable to configure ResourceManagerAccount: subscription ID could not be determined and was not specified

  with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"].second,
  on provider.tf line 81, in provider "azurerm":
  81: provider "azurerm" {

I'm considering breaking the places I use these providers out into a separate module but according to https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/providers all providers are global and so it won't work.
Is there a way to make a provider optional so it will only be loaded if I need it?  Or is my reading of the Docs incorrect?

Try conditionally configuring the provider by count to skip loading when sub_ID is empty
refer: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/configuration#using-count-with-providers @simpleCoder

Where does that doc refer to count in the provider doc?  Terraform complains when I try it.  Do you have a working example?

You can check with this
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/count
&
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/conditionals
@simplecoder to check the working example we need privilege for multiple subscriptions unfortunately I don't have right now.  The work around should be similar as mentioned as blocker is related to referring the subscriptions


Optional provider using terraform

The requirement to use multiple subscription to deploy same resource under each can be achieved by dynamically adjusting the configuration based on Subscription_id under defined variables.
The blocker you're facing due to terraform is trying to fetch the value which you left empty which is not at all valid in terraform case. This can try terraform count parameter this will provide the info of resources conditionally based on available subscription ID.
My terraform configruation:
variable "primary_subscription_id" {
  description = "Primary sub ID"
  type        = string
}

variable "secondary_subscription_id" {
  description = "Secondary sub ID"
  type        = string
 
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source  = "azure/azapi"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias                      = "primary"
  tenant_id                  = "Primary tenentID"
  subscription_id            = var.primary_subscription_id
  skip_provider_registration = true
  use_oidc                   = true
  features {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias                      = "secondary"
  tenant_id                  = "<secondary tenentID>"
  subscription_id            = var.secondary_subscription_id
  skip_provider_registration = true
  use_oidc                   = true
  features {}
}

provider "azapi" {
  alias           = "primary-api"
  tenant_id       = "Primary tenentID"
  subscription_id = var.primary_subscription_id
  use_oidc        = true
}



provider "azapi" {
  alias           = "secondary-api"
  tenant_id       = "Secondary tenentID"
  subscription_id = var.secondary_subscription_id
  use_oidc        = true
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "primary_rg" {
  count    = var.primary_subscription_id != "" ? 1 : 0
  name     = "primary-rg"
  location = "East US"
  provider  =  azurerm.primary
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "secondary_rg" {
  count    = var.secondary_subscription_id != "" ? 1 : 0
  name     = "secondary-rg"
  location = "West US"
  provider  =  azurerm.secondary
}


resource "azapi_resource" "primary_example" {
  count       = var.primary_subscription_id != "" ? 1 : 0
  type        = "Microsoft.Example/exampleResource"
  name        = "primary-example-resource"
  location    = "East US"

  provider = azapi.primary-api
}

resource "azapi_resource" "secondary_example" {
  count       = var.secondary_subscription_id != "" ? 1 : 0
  type        = "Microsoft.Example/exampleResource"
  name        = "secondary-example-resource"
  location    = "West US"
  provider = azapi.secondary-api
}

I provided the info for the two providers you can use based on your requirement.
we need to define the tfvars for each subscription
tfvars:
primary_subscription_id    = "Primary Sub_ID"
secondary_subscription_id  = "Secondary Sub_ID"

& command to execute
terraform apply -var="primary_subscription_id=Primary Sub_ID" -var="secondary_subscription_id=Secondary Sub_ID"

Terraform plan:

Reference:
https://github.com/seifrajhi/terraform-CheatSheet#count
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/configuration

Thank you, that's what I've done in my code. Is the suggestion then that I am missing the count on a resource in my template and it's trying to use the provider and then failing?
Could you try your above configuration with terraform apply -var="primary_subscription_id=Primary Sub_ID" -var="secondary_subscription_id=''"
